# Assign promise return value to an iterator (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-promise

Iterating over objects in CoffeScript I want to calculate and display a certain value for every entry (number of assets in pool)

Controller function:

```
archivedBidParts = []
for day in BidService.activeDays(bid) when DateService.isBetween(day, from, to, true, true)
  splitBidPart = angular.copy(bid_part)
  splitBidPart.hours = BidService.hoursActiveOnDay(day, bid)
  splitBidPart.number_of_assets_in_pool = number_of_assets_in_pool(bid)
  archivedBidParts.push(splitBidPart)
$scope.data.splitBidParts = sort(archivedBidParts)
```

Helper function:

```
number_of_assets_in_pool = (bid) ->
  Pool.query().$promise.then(pool_memberships.bind(null, bid)).then((pool) -> pool.pool_memberships.length)
```

The view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="bid_part in data.splitBidParts">
 ...
  <td ng-hide="bid_part.holidayName">{{ bid_part.number_of_assets_in_pool }}</td>
```

Problem:
The helper function returns a promise. When trying to console.log the return value inside the promise (in the last .then()-statement) the right number gets printed out in the console.

Does someone have an idea how to use the return value to be displayed properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I just updated my question in regards to @zayquan 's comment that the instances of splitBidPart are lost after every loop. They actually get collected in an array and then assigned to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the following line in your controller

```js
splitBidPart.number_of_assets_in_pool = number_of_assets_in_pool(bid)
```

To something like this:

```js
number_of_assets_in_pool(bid).then(function(retval) {
    splitBidPart.number_of_assets_in_pool = retval;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @mark-veenstra. It looked like a good solution. As a result I only get the number display at one of the rows and not on every row.. Any further ideas? Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

For your example you could assign to the `splitBidPart` object in the promise resolution.

If you need to know when all the promises are resolved you will need to collect them and then resolve them with a call to `$q.all()` (note this can be expensive to perform if there are lots of promises).

Note in the example below all the instances of splitBidPart are lost once the loop is complete so this is not a working stand alone example.

Note also you need to provide `$q` via injecting it into the controller.
`promises = []
for day in BidService.activeDays(bid) when DateService.isBetween(day, from, to, true, true)
  splitBidPart = angular.copy(bid_part)
  splitBidPart.hours = BidService.hoursActiveOnDay(day, bid)
  number_of_assets_in_pool(bid).then (theAnswer) ->
    splitBidPart.number_of_assets_in_pool = theAnswer
$q.all(promises).then ->
  console.log "all the promises are resolved"`

Note that in some cases Angular can deal with promises intelligently and it will 'just work'. Would like to articulate this last point but can't really without digging into the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Does the sort function preserve the binding? Can you try what happens when leaving out the sort?

Comment: Thanks @manuel.. The result stays the same.. only one value gets displayed for one element and changes as other elements get loaded..